# Error in Azure Authentication token request

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get the authentication via azure oauth2 api but it is giving me peculiar error. The error message is quite confusing as the I have already provided the grant_type. Please refer the below screenshot

[image]

I am not able to get what I am missing here.
One header I provided - Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Try to change the Body type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. however I remember it was working with form-data earlier. Please post your comment as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the Body type to `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

The Content-Type should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

We can see the Request Example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-service-to-service#service-to-service-access-token-request).

Comment: how can you decode the token to get client details ?

Comment: @DivanshuAggarwal thanks for your comment, but how about asking via position a new question?